# IOS: In WebView javascript/jquery scrollTop on div not working.

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, uiscrollview

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(div_name).scrollTop(1000);"]
```

The above code not works.

I can't use webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,1000). Overflow is not on Body. Overall ScrollView Height is equal to the size of Device height.

Div inside body is fixed and it has overflow.